# How to use type predicates to narrow type to a non-assignable type?

Tags: typescript

I need to filter an array based on the `undefined` state of a specific property in its values. To achieve this, I am using a type predicate to enforce the type of the result of the `filter`. The values in the array contain a required property, which is optional in the type predicate's type.

With the following example ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYjgGwFlsATCfZAbwChll0pt0B+ALmQGcwpQBzAblrJsYABbQACo3TsQAVwC2AI2iCAvtWqhIsRCgBKEAI5zgUCCWJkKNOgybsuPEL2QAfZHJBkYoC4LoRcSgpB2R5ZWh3T28IXxB-ag1qBFwuZDgoKDgAT3ZDEzMLK3IAbQBdZABeZArBagB6BuQACWwAd2QwbGRffB0G1JAAN2gwZAADTOycia6euBAMrNzhGEmMLFwCEvw55k0h9L6dAGlUauWZgDoT6AAKe+GCOQgASnZn-FfkYA40TA4PBEUjkaoAPi6OXQEGw6y+r2uQUk0mQAEIqjUAOReHx+EhYt78IA)):

```
interface OptionalModel {
  prop?: string;
  otherProp: number;
}

interface RequiredModel {
  prop: string | undefined;
  otherProp: number | undefined;
}

const array: RequiredModel[] = [];

// How to filter/convert `array` to an array of `OptionalModel` ?

const filterKO = array.filter((value): value is OptionalModel => typeof value.otherProp !== 'undefined'); // ✗
```

there is an error in the `filterKO` declaration. TS says on `OptionalModel` in type predicate:

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'OptionalModel' is not assignable to type 'RequiredModel'.
    Property 'prop' is optional in type 'OptionalModel' but required in type 'RequiredModel'.(2677)
```

The use of the type predicate is not possible due to the optional property in `OptionalModel` ; but the use of `array` directly as an `OptionalModel[]` is not possible either due to the possibly `undefined` other property in `RequiredModel`.

How can I achieve the filtering , for `filterKO` type to be narrowed to `OptionalModel[]` ?

Comment: `Property 'prop' is optional in type 'OptionalModel' but required in type 'RequiredModel'.` - how can it be any clearer?

Comment: The problem is not that RequiredModel is not of type OptionalModel, but the opposite. OptionalModel is not of type RequiredModel because prop is required in RequiredModel. Your code would work if array was of type OptionalModel[]

Comment: @Lesiak I understand the error TS is giving to me, what I don't get is the _why_. The fact is that I get some data in a type which has required fields, and I need to convert it into a type in which the same fields are optional. So I would expect that, when filtering, I could tell TS to perform the conversion at the same time ?

Comment: It's because [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) are a way of *narrowing*, not widening or mutating a type.  Optional properties are wider than required ones: every `{x: X}` is a `{x?: X}` but not vice versa, since `{}` is the latter but not the former. You don't need a type predicate to widen, just annotate: see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mALGXN). Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your answer, it is clearer now. I however realise that I have missed an important part which is making it more tricky: there is some fields which can be `undefined` in `RequiredModel`, but not in `OptionalModel` - while still being required. See [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXgP9W) for clearer example. I realize that the objective is actually more like filtering (but conversion is still needed), sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Okay, then it's neither a widening nor a narrowing but a lateral type mutation. I'd say you really have an `(OptionalModel | RequiredModel)[]` and you're narrowing that, which should work. But you can't mutate an `OptionalModel` into a `RequiredModel` or vice versa, that's not how the TS type system works.  So, can I write up an answer to the original question as asked? Or do you want to [edit] to modify its scope to something else?

Comment: Oh okay, indeed the widening before filtering with the type predicates works well, thanks! I think it is better for me to change the question, as it fits the actual problem better and may be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript mostly doesn't model arbitrary mutations of types. The language doesn't want to let you take a value `v` of type `V` and just *change*  its type to type `W`, for arbitrary `V` and `W`.

Instead it models two basic type changes.  The first is *widening*, which is (to a first approximation) safe.  If every value of type `V` is also a value of type `W`, then you can safely assign a `V` where a `W` is expected. You don't need type predicates or anything else for this; just assign it to a new variable [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with the wider type:

The second is [*narrowing*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), which is generally unsafe. If every value of type `W` is also a value of type `V`, but if not every value of type `V` is also a value of type `W`, then you can't just assign a `V` where a `W` is expected.  Instead, to be safe, you should perform some kind of *type guarding* on your `V` to make sure it is also a `W`.  TypeScript has a bunch of facilities to do this, including [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which let you write custom type guard functions.

---

But you can't get from `RequiredModel` to `OptionalModel` directly via widening or via narrowing.  Neither `RequiredModel` nor `OptionalModel` is assignable to the other.  So you can't use either of the widening or the narrowing approaches right immediately.

Still, it's not impossible.  Even if neither `V` nor `W` is a subtype of the other, you can always introduce a third type and use it as an intermediary.  For example, the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `V | W` is a widening of both `V` and `W`.  Every value of type `V` is assignable to type `V | W`.  And every value of type `W` is also assignable to type `V | W`.  So you can freely widen from `V` to `V | W`, and then use a narrowing technique to narrow from `V | W` to `W`.

---

Here's how that looks:

```
const array: RequiredModel[] = [];

const widenedArray:
  (RequiredModel | OptionalModel)[] = array; // okay

const filtered = widenedArray.filter(
  (value): value is OptionalModel => typeof value.otherProp !== 'undefined'
);
// const filtered: OptionalModel[] // okay
```

First we widen `array` from `RequiredModel[]` to `(RequiredModel | OptionalModel)[]` by copying its reference to `widenedArray`.  And then we narrow `widenedArray` from `(RequiredModel | OptionalModel)[]` to `OptionalModel[]` via the type predicate callback to `filter()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYjgGwFlsATCfZAbwChll0pt0B+ALmQGcwpQBzAblrJsYABbQACo3TsQAVwC2AI2iCAvtWqhIsRCgBKEAI5zgUCCWJkKNOgybsuPEL2QAfZHJBkYoC4LoRcSgpB2R5ZWh3T28IXxB-ag1NBFwuZDgoKDgAT3ZDEzMLK3IAbQBdZABeZArBalSQdIB3YDIEkgBBLNzWIQAKAtNzS1JyaIwsXAIS-ABKCuqMnpz+ZAB6deEAa1yUtLBkX3wdCyXW9otu7JyAOmOdfoGANwI5CDn2V-x35GAONCYHB4IhjChVAB8yDAOXQEGwMGQ33etyCkmkyAAhFUagByLw+PwkXHUOaCTbIRrpB7QCzsSbAmZgirUIA)